# MySQL to PostgreSQL master-slave replication using tungsten replicator

Tags: mysql, postgresql, master-slave, tungsten-replicator

I would like to create a master-slave replication system where the master is running on a MySQL server and slave on a PostgreSQL server. Currently I am trying to set this up using tungsten replicator. The official documentation of latest version does not have the procedure for setting this up. But the old versions have it([here](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCHeterogeneousReplication#MySQL_to_PostgreSQL_and_Oracle_Replication)).

Is it possible to set-up the replication using latest version? If so, can someone please explain the procedure to set it up.

Also which of the following software would you suggest I use for creating the above mentioned master-slave replication system:

-> Tungsten Replicator

-> SymmetricDS

-> [Flexible Replication](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/flexrep)

Comment: why not use mysql for master and slave? easy to set up...

Comment: We are thinking of move our data from MySQL to PostgreSQL, but first we would like to have a slave in PostgreSQL for some time before moving the production server as well.